# What does "->" mean/refer to in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, syntax

What does `->` mean/refer to in PHP?

In the following from WordPress, I know what the `if` statement  does, for example, but what does the `->`  do?

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
```

Comment: @Jimmy the funniest thing is that your Google query returns nothing useful. You should probably work on your Google skillz before you pull this one again

Comment: yeah, i realized that... but it is possible to get around getting NO results

Comment: @Jimmy LMGTFY is discouraged on SO

Comment: `$object->property`, `$object->method()` ... properties are basically class/object variables, whilst methods are class/object functions.

Comment: The "duplicate question" reference points to a page which links to this question. That's a bit awkward.

Comment: Tip: Use http://symbolhound.com to search for things with weird symbols in them (ie. things that Google won't search for)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`->` accesses a member of an object. So `$wp_query->max_num_pages` is accessing the field `max_num_pages` in the object `$wp_query`. It can be used to access either a method or a field belonging to an object, and if you're familiar with C++ or Java, it's equivalent to `myObject.myField`

Comment: O dear. Hit enter too fast.  So something like `<?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>` is really saying: 

`<?php $comment = function stuff 
 if $comment_approved =='0' {
  do something else in here
 }else{
  do this other thing 
 }

?>`

Comment: @saltcod you can edit comments for about 5 minutes after they post them. What that's saying is, in this object `$comment`, if the comment is not approved, do something, else do something completely different. You pretty much have it down. Objects are cool because you can store a ton of relevant information about the object in a convenient, logical place (like the comment author, the text of the comment, whether or not it was approved, when it was left, etc.)

Comment: So basically, just by naming the object and 'pointing' it at function using `->`, it's replacing the long-form if-else statements?

Comment: @saltcod it's saving you from defining a bunch of different related variables with no real association. That way, when you want info about a comment, you've got a good place to look. Object-oriented programming is a big concept best learned at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 28):

Firstly you should understand the following. In PHP and many other languages we have the following types of entites:

- Variables
- Arrays
- Objects

The `->` allows you to access a method or value within an object, the same way that `[]` allows you to access values within an array.

A class is like a box, and within that box there is a lot of items, and each item can interact with each other as they are within the same box.

For example:

```
class Box
{
    function firstItem()
    {

    }


    function secondItem()
    {

    }
}
```

The above is what we call a class. It's basically a structured piece of code that does not really do anything until it becomes an **object**.

The object is created by using the `new` keyword, which instantiates a class and creates an objects from it.

```
$box = new Box;
```

Now the above `$box`, which is an object created from the Box class, has methods inside, such as `firstItem()`.

These are just like functions apart from within them we have another variable called `$this` and this is used to access other methods within that object.

Now to access the methods from outside the objects you have to use the operator described in your question.

```
$box->firstItem();
```

The operator `->` will allow you to execute the method from the variable `$box`.

Comment: Exactly, For all of them read here. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: This is a very concise answer that also provides an amazing example, definitely helped me understand EXACTLY what was going on!

Comment: This answer is really amazing. THANKS!

Comment: It makes me understand better how to use`$this`. Do you have similar answer about what the `::` means?

Answer (score 6):

It's like the period (.) in JavaScript and Java. It is just a simple access operator.

Answer (score 5):

-> is the used to access methods and attributes of an object.  See the [PHP manual on classes and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid it was going to be objects and classes.

Comment: @saltcod why? Objects and classes are generally nice to have :)

Comment: An attribute may be another object.

Comment: don't be afraid of objects and classes, they are your friend :D

Answer (score 3):

It accesses a member of the object on the left with the name on the right.

Answer (score 3):

It accesses the member of the object; $obj->prop accesses the "prop" property of whatever object is in the $obj variable.

In many other programming languages, a period is used for this purpose: obj.prop or obj.method(), for example.

Answer (score 2):

**It is how PHP handles objects.** Essentially, `$wp_query` is an object that has methods (functions) and attributes that can be accessed through the `->` characters.

PHP didn't start with objects so you see it now as sort of an afterthought. I find `->` to be a messy way to handle it, compared to say Ruby, which was built with objects from the foundation.

You can find more at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to understand.

In PHP we use -> to access a method/property defined inside a class.

So in your case ($wp_query->max_num_pages), you are trying the get the value of max_num_pages which is a variable of $wp_query class.

$wp_query object information defining the current request, and then $wp_query determines what type of query it's dealing with (possibly a category archive, dated archive, feed, or search), and fetches the requested posts. It retains a lot of information on the request, which can be pulled at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Main{
 private $name = 'My Name is Febri.<br/>';
 private function print_name(){
  echo $this -> name;
 }
}

class Descend extends Main{
 function print(){
  $this -> print_name();
 }
}

$try = new Descend;
$try -> print();
echo $try -> name;
?>
```

From the example above, we can not call a function which is a private print_name method. In addition, we also can not call the name variable which is set as private property.

Answer (score 0):

`->` is basically used to access a filed of an object. Analogioous to attributes in Java.

for eg.

```
class Student {
String name;
int rollno;
}
```

Student.name accesses the name of a given student object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `->` to access fields, methods in an object, it is parallel to `[]` in array variables (`$array['field']`  is `$object->field`). In WP you'll use it on `$post` for example, since it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

`$object->property` is used to access the property of any object.

Comment: It is generally not good to post something that was already said by basically every other answer 3 years ago. You should have introduced something new to warrant a new answer.