# Php sub-methods

Tags: php, cakephp

I've used php enough to be quite comfortable with it, but recently I've been looking through some MVC frameworks to try and understand how they work, and I've come across a syntax and data structure which I haven't encountered before:

```
function view($id)   
   {   
       $this->Note->id = $id;   
   }
```

What is the ->id section of this code? Is this a sub-method based off it's parent method? If so, how do I go about writing code to create such a structure? (ie. creating the structure from scratch, not using an existing framework like the above example from cakephp).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolutely basic PHP question about the "-> " syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502587/absolutely-basic-php-question-about-the-syntax)

Comment: *(related)* [Reference: What does this symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: This would be a method in a class. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: It's `$note = $this->Note; $note->id = $id`

Comment: It essentially means that $this->Note is itself an object with the proprety $id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code demonstrates how one could arrive at the structure you described.

```
<?php

class Note
{
    public $id = 42;
}

class MyClass
{
    public function __construct() {
        // instance of 'Note' as a property of 'MyClass'
        $this->Note = new Note();
    }

    public function test() {
        printf("The \$id property in our instance of 'Note' is: %d\n",
            $this->Note->id);
    }
}

$mc = new MyClass();
$mc->test();
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `MyClass` have `var $Note` before the constructor?

Comment: There is no requirement to declare instance properties, but you are right - it is probably "more correct".  BTW, 'public' or 'private' is preferred over 'var'.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: you dont have to declare anything in php

Comment: @dogmatic69: That is an absolutely false statement.

Answer (score 2):

`Note` is a property of `$this` and it's (current) value is an object with a property named `id` which gets assigned the value of `$id`.
If `id` was a method of the `Note` object, the line would read `$this->Note->id($id);`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think about the construct is considering

```
 $this->Note->id = $id;
```

similar to

```
 $this["Note"]["id"] = $id;
```

Which would actually be equivalent if both objects ($this and subobject Note) were based on ArrayAccess.